# Regular Expression to match a sequence

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost, match

I want a regeular expression to match a sequence.
The sequence in which i want the regular expression to match is NP so to make sure all the way down the string that after the N there is a P and that before the P there is an N

**1) NPNPNPNP = correct**

**2)NPNPPNP = incorrect**

SORRY GUYS I MISSED ONE MORE PART FROM THE QUESTION THE 3RD MATCH WOULD BE

**3)NNNPNPNNP = correct** SO THERE CAN BE MANY N's but at the end of the N there has to be a P to follow like above

But i do not think my regular expression is correct, can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
std::string a ("NPNPNPPN");
 boost::regex const string_matcher("\(NP\)*");
 if(boost::regex_match(a,string_matcher))
 {
     DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Yes it Matches ");
 }
 else
 {
     DCS_LOG_DEBUG("No it does not Match");
 }
```

Comment: `i do not think my regular expression is correct` Why? Which of your tests fail? Why do you escape the `(` and `)`?

Comment: The answers below vary as to whether or not the empty string `""` succeeds or fails.  Which is it?  And can you have non-NP letters before or after the sequence, or can the string only consist of pairs of `NP`?

Comment: Yeah i do not think i need to escape the `(` and `)` thinking about it now @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: the empty `""` will not always suceed sometimes the order may be **NPPN** in that case i need to signal an error @MikeRyan

Comment: I don't think you understand my first question -- either `""` succeeds or it fails.  By using `*` in your original code you imply it should succeed, but your works suggest that you're not thinking of this case. **NPPN** is not an example of an empty string.  As for my second, I'm asking if "123NPNP" should succeed or fail?

Comment: "123NPNP" would not succeed, the only characters in string a will either be N or P i extract the N and P character from a vector which are then put into `string a` the other order which it will have to succeed with is **NNNPNP** aswell so multiple N's before a P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: updated per the requirements changes and comments & suggestions

```
^(N+P)+$
```

[Here it is with some tests](http://rubular.com/r/9nBm1STsYS)

Further reading on regular expressions http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Why not add a `regex_constants::icase` to the regex constructor instead of repeating these letters?

Comment: because then I can't test it in rubular

Comment: the other order which it will have to succeed with is **NNNPNP** aswell so multiple N's before a P

Comment: For case-insensitive, sure you can test in Rubular.  If you add an `i` to the options field on the right (after the `/`), that's Ruby's version of case-insenstivity.

Answer (score 2):

For your revised question, where NP pairs consist of 1 or more N's always followed by a single P, the regex would be:

```
^(?:N+P)+$
```

- That's a non-capturing parentheses  `(?:`
- Followed by 1 or more N's  `N+`
- Followed by a P:  `P`
- Close Parentheses, to allow us to match on NP type pairs:  `)`
- Followed by a `+` to ensure that atleast one NP type pair exists.  (i.e. there must be something to match.
- With the whole expression surrounded w/ ^ and + so that it's only NP type pairs.

And if you want it to be case-insensitive, add `regex_constants::icase` to the regex constructor.

Answer (score 0):

With boost regular expressions, `^(?:[^NP]*NP)*[^NP]*$` should do the trick, I
think.  A sequence of anything other than `N` or `P`, followed by `NP`,
repeated as often as possible, followed by anything other than an `N` or
a `P`.  Starting at the beginning of the text, and continuing until the
end.  (If no characters other than `N` and `P` are allowed, then
`^(?:NP)*$` is all that is needed.)

This is using the default settings (Perl regular expressions, I think).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 boost::regex const string_matcher("^(NP)*$");
```

Comment: Yes the other match is `NNNPNPNP` so multiple N's before a P aswel thats just a * after the N right? @LightnessRacesinOrbit